# Time Slot not working if time exceeds the slot size

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, time

I have two tables. One that has the slot info and the other that saves the slot that is selected.

> Rule[image]

> Booking table[image]

now The code I am using is

```
 declare  @RuleId int,@starttime varchar(50),@endtime varchar(50),@r int,@interval int
 SELECT
 @RuleId=Rules.Rule_Serno,
   @starttime = Rules.from_dt
 , @endtime   = Rules.to_dt
 ,@r=Rules.room,
  @interval  = Service.Service_Duration
  FROM         Service INNER JOIN
                       Rules ON Service.Service_Serno = Rules.Service_Id where Service.Service_Serno=@ServiceId
 --SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM d;

  declare @slots int

  select @slots = datediff(minute, @starttime, @endtime)/@interval

  SELECT TOP (@slots) N=IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1)
  INTO #Numbers
  FROM master.dbo.syscolumns a CROSS JOIN master.dbo.syscolumns  b;

  select 
      dateadd(minute,((n-1)*@interval),@starttime) as start,
      dateadd(minute,(n*@interval),@starttime) as todate
  into
      #slots
  from
      #numbers

 SELECT  @room as RoomId,@Dt as 'Date',LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,s.start, 108), 10)  as Start,LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,s.todate, 108), 10) as 'End', case when b.start IS null then '-' else 'xx' end as Status
 FROM         [#slots] AS s left JOIN
                       booking AS b ON s.start = b.start AND s.todate = b.todate and b.Dt=@Dt  and b.Service_Id=@ServiceId and b.Room_Id=@room


  drop table #numbers,  #slots
```

The issue is the code only works if the slots are precisely the minutes described in the table .. For example if the slot is for 60 minutes ex:if I book that and if I book manually 7:00 to 7:30 it still shows the 7:00-8:00 slot empty. I need to show anything between the slot also reserved if it is manually done beside the reserved slot.

Comment: What that code is supposed to do? BTW: Do not use `master` database in your queries.

Comment: can you show us all the related table schema ?

Comment: @SlavaMurygin what it does is create slots with respect to the slot duration given in the **Rule** table. For example if the slot duration is 60 then it creates slots of 60 min .
2.there are only two tables. Rules and booking rest is all at run-time.

Comment: 1. You do not have create/insert script to test. 2. your script is not working at all. 3. Provide desired result set. 4. Instead Date+Time columns use DATETIME one.